# Create a dataframe based on 3 linked dataframes using a constraint on cumsum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I do have three dataframes like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'C1': [2, 7, 3, 6, 5, 3],
        'C2': [0, 8, 0, 1, 0, 0]
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'position1': range(11, 17),
        'column': ['C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C2'],
        'mapper': list('aababb')
    }
)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'position2': range(1, 7),
        'C1': list('aabbab'),
        'C2': list('abbbaa')
    }
)
```

that looks as follows

```
   C1  C2
0   2   0
1   7   8
2   3   0
3   6   1
4   5   0
5   3   0

  position1 column mapper
0         11     C1      a
1         12     C2      a
2         13     C1      b
3         14     C1      a
4         15     C1      b
5         16     C2      b

   position2 C1 C2
0          1  a  a
1          2  a  b
2          3  b  b
3          4  b  b
4          5  a  a
5          6  b  a
```

and I would like to create another dataframe using these 3 dataframes that looks as follows:

```
   position1  position2  value
0          11          1      2
1          11          2      7
2          13          3      3
3          13          4      6
4          14          5      5
5          15          6      3
6          12          1      0
7          16          2      8
8          16          3      0
9          16          4      1
10         12          5      0
11         12          6      0
```

Here is the logic for `C1`:

1. First, one checks the first value in column `C1` in `df3` which is an `a`.
2. Second, one checks in `df2` where one first finds the letter determined in 1) - in our case an `a` for the respective column (here: `C1`) and notes down the value of `position1` (here: `11`).
3. Now one goes to `df1` and notes down the respective value for `C1` (here: `2`)
4. That gives us the first row of the desired outcome: `position2 = 1`, `position1 = 11` and the `value = 2`.

So far, so good. The issue comes in due to a constraint:

In `df2` each `position1` can only be used as long as the sum of all corresponding values from `df1` do not exceed `10`; if that happens the next valid position in `df2` should be found.

So, for the example above:
In `df3` if I go to the next row in `C1` I again find an `a`, therefore I again check `df2` and end up again with `position1 = 11`. If I check in `df1` I find a value of `7`, the cumulative sum would be `9` which is below `10`, so all good and I have the next row of my desired dataframe:
`position2 = 2`, `position1 = 11` and the `value = 7`.

Now I go to the next row in `df3` in column `C1` and find a `b`, checking `df2` gives me position `13` and the value from `df` is `3`, so I get the row:
`position2 = 3`, `position1 = 13` and the `value = 3`.

Doing it once more gives
`position2 = 4`, `position1 = 13` and the `value = 6`.

Doing it again, gives me now letter `a` again which would point to `position1 = 11` in `df2`. The value from `df1` is `5`; as the cumulative sum is already `9`, I cannot use this position but have to find the next one in `df2` which is `position2 = 14`. Therefore I can add the row:
`position2 = 5`, `position1 = 14` and the `value = 5`.

And so on...

I am struggling with incorporating the check for the `cumsum`. Does anyone see an elegant solution to create the desired dataframe from the 3 inputs? Only solutions I have contain several loops and the code is not very readable.

The example might be tricky to follow but I could not design an easier one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The answer by @mitoRibo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71344745/1534017) got me on the right track; `pd.melt` is indeed key to solve it, it seems. Here is my solution with a few comments:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def assign_group_memberships(aniterable, max_sum):
    label = 0
    total_sum = 0
    for val in aniterable:
        total_sum += val
        if total_sum > max_sum:
            total_sum = val
            label += 1
        yield label

# copy df1, df2 and df3 from the question
desired = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'position1': [11, 11, 13, 13, 14, 15, 12, 16, 16, 16, 12, 12],
        'position2': list(range(1, 7)) + list(range(1, 7)),
        'value': [2, 7, 3, 6, 5, 3, 0, 8, 0, 1, 0, 0]
    }
)

threshold = 10

# Convert df1 and df3 to long form
df1_long = df1.melt(
    var_name='column'
)

df3_long = df3.melt(
    id_vars='position2',
    var_name='column',
    value_name='mapper',
)

df3_long['value'] = df1_long['value'].copy()
```

Now we can assign groups to the individual rows based on `threshold`: whenever `threshold` is exceeded, a new `label` is created for each `column, mapper` group.

```
df3_long['group'] = (
    df3_long.groupby(['column', 'mapper'])['value'].transform(
        lambda x: assign_group_memberships(x, threshold)
    )
)

    position2 column mapper  value  group
0           1     C1      a      2      0
1           2     C1      a      7      0
2           3     C1      b      3      0
3           4     C1      b      6      0
4           5     C1      a      5      1
5           6     C1      b      3      1
6           1     C2      a      0      0
7           2     C2      b      8      0
8           3     C2      b      0      0
9           4     C2      b      1      0
10          5     C2      a      0      0
11          6     C2      a      0      0
```

Now we can also determine the respective group labels in `df2`

```
df2['group'] = df2.groupby(['column', 'mapper']).cumcount()

   position1 column mapper  group
0         11     C1      a      0
1         12     C2      a      0
2         13     C1      b      0
3         14     C1      a      1
4         15     C1      b      1
5         16     C2      b      0
```

and the only thing left to do is to merge `df2` and `df3_long`

```
result = df3_long.merge(df2, on=['column', 'mapper', 'group'])

    position2 column mapper  value  group  position1
0           1     C1      a      2      0         11
1           2     C1      a      7      0         11
2           3     C1      b      3      0         13
3           4     C1      b      6      0         13
4           5     C1      a      5      1         14
5           6     C1      b      3      1         15
6           1     C2      a      0      0         12
7           5     C2      a      0      0         12
8           6     C2      a      0      0         12
9           2     C2      b      8      0         16
10          3     C2      b      0      0         16
11          4     C2      b      1      0         16
```

Now we can check whether `result` is equal to `desired`

```
result = (
    result[
        ['position1', 'position2', 'value']
    ].sort_values(['position1', 'position2']).reset_index(drop=True)
)

desired = (
    desired.sort_values(
        ['position1', 'position2']
    ).reset_index(drop=True)
)

print(result.equals(desired))
```

which is indeed the case.

Might be better options, so, please post them! And thanks again to mitoRibo for the inspiration!

Comment: very nice solution! this scales much better and is easy to read imho. determining "group" from `df3` and `df1` together before introducing `df2` works really nicely

Comment: Thanks @mitoRibo! Would not have been possible without your nice answer. :) There is still a time constraint on the bounty; should be possible to reward it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that aggregates all the tables together representing all options of which `position1` to use and then removes the options that surpass that 10 count threshold. This doesn't scale well when a letter in `df3` has many options in `df2`.

Couldn't figure out to do this without a loop. Currently performs cumsum and removal of counts over threshold

```
threshold = 10

#Convert df1 and df3 to long form
df3_long = df3.melt(
    id_vars = 'position2',
    var_name = 'column',
    value_name = 'mapper',
)

#Merge info from across the three dfs into a single df
m = df3_long.merge(
    df2,
    on = ['mapper','column'],
    how = 'right',
)
m['value'] = m.apply(lambda r: df1.loc[r.position2-1][r.column], axis=1)


#Iteratively remove duplicates and redo cumsum (expensive operation!)
while True:
    #Count the running tally of the position1 usage and filter out overusage
    m['cumsum_score'] = m.groupby('position1')['value'].transform('cumsum')
    passing = m['cumsum_score'].le(threshold)
    
    is_dup = m.duplicated(['position2','column'],keep=False)
    not_first_dup = m.duplicated(['position2','column'])
    is_first_dup = is_dup & ~not_first_dup

    #successful stop when all duplicates are removed and all are passing
    if all(~is_dup) & all(passing):
        break
        
    #unsuccesful stop when all duplicates are removed, but still not all passing
    if all(~is_dup) & ~all(passing):
        print('ERROR')
        break
    
    m = m.loc[
        (passing & ~is_dup) |
        (passing & is_first_dup) |
        (~passing & not_first_dup)
    ]
    
#Format the output
m = m.sort_values(['column','position2'])
m = m[['position1','position2','value']].reset_index(drop=True)

m
```

Comment: Thanks, that indeed gives the desired output (already upvoted). I'll play with it a bit and get back to you probably by the end of the weekend.

Comment: That answer got me on the right track. I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71355335/1534017) below which might be more efficient. Once it is possible to award a bounty, I will do it, as promised. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I did not get it how do you get `position1` in your last table but I have found that you can get the table this way.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'C1': [2, 7, 3, 6, 5, 3],
        'C2': [0, 8, 0, 1, 0, 0]
    }
)
df1 = pd.melt(df1, var_name='column')

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'position1': range(11, 17),
        'column': ['C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C2'],
        'mapper': list('aababb')
    }
)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'position2': range(1, 7),
        'C1': list('aabbab'),
        'C2': list('abbbaa')
    }
)
df3 = pd.melt(df3,id_vars=['position2'] ,var_name='column',value_name='mapper')
df4=pd.concat([df1, df3])
df=pd.concat([df4,df2])

df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
df = df[df['value'].notna()]

print(df)
```

The results will be similar to this

```
 column  value  position2 mapper  position1
0      C1    2.0        1.0      a       11.0
1      C1    7.0        2.0      a       12.0
2      C1    3.0        3.0      b       13.0
3      C1    6.0        4.0      b       14.0
4      C1    5.0        5.0      a       15.0
5      C1    3.0        6.0      b       16.0
6      C2    0.0        1.0      a        NaN
7      C2    8.0        2.0      b        NaN
8      C2    0.0        3.0      b        NaN
9      C2    1.0        4.0      b        NaN
10     C2    0.0        5.0      a        NaN
11     C2    0.0        6.0      a        NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, will take a look later. What about the `NaNs` though? `position1` should not be empty anywhere.

Comment: Actually, I did not find the pattern of how do you select `position1` and that may not be the full answer but it may help you to get the same table.