# Create dictionary from several columns based on position of values

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dictionary

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'C1': list('aabbab'),
        'C2': list('abbbaa'),
        'value': range(11, 17)
    }
)

  C1 C2  value
0  a  a     11
1  a  b     12
2  b  b     13
3  b  b     14
4  a  a     15
5  b  a     16
```

and I would like to generate a dictionary like this:

```
{'C1': {'a': {1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 15}, 'b': {1: 13, 2: 14, 3: 16}},
'C2': {'a': {1: 11, 2: 15, 3: 16}, 'b': {1: 12, 2: 13, 3: 14}}}
```

Logic is as follows:

In `df` I go to the column `C1` and the first `a` I find in the column corresponds to value `11`, the second one to value `12` and the third one to `15`. The position of the `a` and the corresponding value should be stored in the dictionary for the keys `C1` and `a`.

I could do something like this

```
df_ss = df.loc[df['C1'] == 'a', 'value']
d = {ind: val for ind, val in enumerate(df_ss.values, 1)}
```

which yields for `d`:

```
{1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 15}
```

which is indeed the desired output. I could then put this into a loop and generate all required dictionaries.

Does anyone sees something more efficient than this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a groupby and a nested dict comprehension:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'C1': list('aabbab'),
        'C2': list('abbbaa'),
        'value': range(11, 17)
    }
)

d = {
    c: {k: dict(enumerate(g["value"], 1)) for k, g in df.groupby(c)}
    for c in ["C1", "C2"]
}
```

Which outputs:

```
{'C1': {'a': {1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 15}, 'b': {1: 13, 2: 14, 3: 16}},
 'C2': {'a': {1: 11, 2: 15, 3: 16}, 'b': {1: 12, 2: 13, 3: 14}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a dictionary comprehension on the [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for each C-value with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
cols = ['C1', 'C2']
# or, programmatically
# cols = df.filter(regex='^C').columns

out = {c: {k: dict(enumerate(g, start=1)) for k,g in df.groupby(c)['value']} 
       for c in cols}
```

output:

```
{'C1': {'a': {1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 15}, 'b': {1: 13, 2: 14, 3: 16}},
 'C2': {'a': {1: 11, 2: 15, 3: 16}, 'b': {1: 12, 2: 13, 3: 14}}}
```

Comment: BTW: there is another one I struggle with which is far more complex: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71315509/create-a-dataframe-based-on-3-linked-dataframes-using-a-constraint-on-cumsum). If you have time... ;)

Comment: @Cleb I've seen (and bookmarked) it, but I haven't had the time to sit down to understand all the details, seems not trivial ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bit slower than @mozway and @Alex methods:

```
{
    c: df.set_index([df.groupby(c).cumcount() + 1, c])["value"]
         .unstack(0)
         .to_dict("index")
    for c in ["C1", "C2"]
}
```

Output:

```
{'C1': {'a': {1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 15}, 'b': {1: 13, 2: 14, 3: 16}},
 'C2': {'a': {1: 11, 2: 15, 3: 16}, 'b': {1: 12, 2: 13, 3: 14}}}
```